# Test controller Cakephp 2 method with array

Tags: cakephp, testing, phpunit, cakephp-2.1

Hi I have this method in controller

```
 public function registeruser($data){
    var_dump($data);
    if(($data) && ($this->User->create($data))) {
      if($data['User']['password'] != Security::hash($data['User']['confirm_password'], null, true) ){
        $this->Session->setFlash('las contraseñas no coinciden');
        // unset($this->data['User']['password']);
        // unset($this->data['User']['confirm_password']);
        $this->redirect('index');
      }
      else if($this->User->save($data)) {
         $this->_subscribMailchimp($data);

      }else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('El mail no es valido o ya está registrado.');
        unset($data['User']['password']);
        unset($data['User']['confirm_password']);
        $this->redirect('index');
      }
    }else {
      $this->Session->setFlash('No se ha podido registrar.');
      $this->redirect('index');
    }
    return $this->User->getLastInsertID();
}
```

I need pass $data form test Controller

```
    $data = array('User' => array('name' => 'Luis jose',
                                  'address' => 'el quinto pino',
                                  'zip' => '28012',
                                  'city' => 'Madrid',
                                  'province' => '5',
                                  'email' => 'luis@hotmail.com',
                                  'password' => Security::hash(Configure::read('Security.salt') . '12345'),
                                  'confirm_password' => '12345'));
    $this->testAction('/users/registeruser', array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'get'));
```

I have tried with this array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'get').
The controller function does not receive the array

Answer (score 0):

Your register user expects 1 paramter ($data), so the URL should look like this:

/foo/registeruser/bar

Which would populate $data with 'bar'

You should try debug($this->request) to see the results of passing the data with GET or better yet, use a POST and check out $this->request->data (CakePHP 2) or $this->data (CakePHP 1.3)

Comment: Hi! an array by passing it the url? i'm no understand.